# Is dynamic meta setting (helmet) useless for SEO if you're not using "ssr" react? (next, gatsby)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got myself in a rabbit hole when trying to implement SEO in my SPA.

My page has `/about` and `/blog` routes.

`/blog` client-side renders a `/nav` with a `href` list to individual blog posts, each with its one "mocked" url which I'm handling through history API and a node greedy route.

I want my blog posts to be index-able by google. Not only that, I want my blog pages to have previewable links when their url is pasted on other websites that support it.

This led me to [Google's SEO for Javascript guide](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/javascript/javascript-seo-basics) and [Open Graph Pattern for links previewing](https://betterprogramming.pub/link-previews-more-than-meets-the-eye-aa13c77c6d69), which made crystal clear I need to properly refer `href`and set some `meta` tags.

I'm facing issues with setting `meta` tags. I know `react helmet` for instance can handle meta tags.

The issue is, as dynamic content is being rendered by browsers, it's not available in the HTML via a simple `get` request. One need to crawl it with a headless browser to render javascript. Google crawler can crawl dynamic webpages, but many other services don't.

So, how useful is helmet for SEO in fact? Is it really useless if you're not server side rendering each page?